# Make a hemisphere volume semitransparent

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, transparency, shapes

I have a hemisphere on the vertical axis, and would like to make it semitransparent (with the borders fading all around, in a sort of field).

[image: hemifield]
I tried using pcolor3, but I do not know how to attach X,Y,Z and V to the function.

Does anybody know how to do it?

```
%Make Sphere
[X,Y,Z] = sphere;      %# Makes a 21-by-21 point sphere

%Make Hemisphere on vertical axis
X = X(:,6:16);       %# Keep top 11 x points
Y = Y(:,6:16);       %# Keep top 11 y points
Z = Z(:,6:16);       %# Keep top 11 z points

r = 1;                 %# A radius value

%Plot
figure
surf(r.*X,r.*Y,r.*Z, 'FaceColor', [0.5 0.5 0.5]);  %# Plot the hemisphere in gray
axis equal;            %# Make the scaling on the x, y, and z axes equal

%Axese limits + View
xlim([0 1])
ylim([-1.5 1.5])
zlim([-1.5 1.5])
view(124, 28)

% pcolor3(X,Y,Z,V) ???
```

Something like this (but only one shape, and a hemisphere):

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you mean with semi-transparent!

But with the face transparency property of the `surf` function you can specify the transperancy level of the faces.

```
surf(..., 'FaceAlpha',0.2)
```

more details and options cf. [MATLAB doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html#bvgs7wv-1)

**Update for a "more" volume like plot**

Okay I see, the issue is, that `surf`/`sphere` command generates just a surface, i.e. its hollow. So even with fading edges it probably wont show what you want. One possibility would be to build a volume with multiple spheres, see example below.

hope this helps

```
n = 20;
[x,y,z] = sphere(n);
x(:,n/2+1:end) = [];
y(:,n/2+1:end) = [];
z(:,n/2+1:end) = [];

C = ones(size(z));

radius = 0.1:0.03:1;

figure
for idx=1:numel(radius)
    r = radius(idx);
    surf(x*r,y*r,z*r,C*r,'FaceAlpha',.2*(1-r), 'EdgeColor','none', 'FaceColor','interp')
    hold on
end
colorbar

axis equal
```

resulting plot:
[image: example result]

Comment: Hello, FaceAlph makes the hemisphere transparent, but I would like to have it fading at the edges, in a sort of "field" (like the blue/red fields above)

Comment: ive updated the original answer with a possible solution - is this more what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello, thanks for this! It is very close but not yet. I tried as you did with the -sphere- command. As you did, it returns the coordinates as 3 2d matrixes for X,Y and Z. 
The function which is supposed to create the field is pcolor3(X,Y,Z,V). The coordinates are ok, but I do not understand how to add the V (the volume). It is supposed to be a 3D matrix but I do not understand how to create it from X,Y,Y.